# Can you use <a> without <p>?

Tags: html

Is it okay to create a list like this?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or should I always add a `<p>`?

```
<ul>
  <li><p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p></li>
  <li><p><a href="#">Item 4</a></p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<p>` element is an inline element for text. You are allowed to insert whatever you like inside it since links are also inline elements.

A list item (`<li>`) is also an inline element. So you can put other inline elements in there too.

Just consider that a `<p>` tag has some built-in styling like a margin.

Answer (score 2):

No `<p>` is needed, `<li>` already indicates the type of the item (it's a list item).

[This w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) shows how there's no need for a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is perfectly fine. p is not needed to declare a link

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is not neccessary in a list, however if you need to put a `<p>` element within a list, the correct way is to put it inside `<a>` tags

for example

```
<li><a href="#"><p>Item 3</p></a></li>
```